# Bootstrap 4 sticky nav with media query problem

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For my Bootstrap 4 project I found a sticky nav script which works fine. But I don't want the script for my smallest breakpoint. (less than 992px).

I've tried : if ($(window).width() >= 992) {} but that doesn't seem to work

This is my code without and with the query :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stickyNavTop = $('.navbar').offset().top;
    var stickyNav = function(){
       var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
            $('.navbar').addClass('sticky');

        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    };

    stickyNav();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    });
});

if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var stickyNavTop = $('.navbar').offset().top;
        var stickyNav = function(){
           var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
            if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
                $('.navbar').addClass('sticky');

            } else {
                $('.navbar').removeClass('sticky');
            }
        };

        stickyNav();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            stickyNav();
        });
    });
}
```

The above code should only apply to screens wider/equal than 992px

Live view of my project so far : http://www.pixelsendots.be/klanten/aloca/

Comment: if ($(window).width() < 992) why not working ?

Comment: The script doesn't work at all if I add it : if ($(window).width() >= 992) {}; Not for any screen width...

Comment: add into interval and check it again

Comment: Seems to work this way : if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop && ($(window).width() >= 992)) {} Tx Nisharg Shah